# WPF: is data binding considerable for modal dialogs?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, modal-dialog

(I'm pretty new to WPF, so this question may seem obvious or inconsistent.)

There is a requirement to edit some piece of application's underlying business data from a child modal window, and to update the data only if the user presses OK button in this window. Let's call this window SettingsDialog.

In this case, is it still reasonable to use WPF data binding to bind SettingsDialog's controls to business data? (And if so, how to update business data only when the user presses SettingsDialog's OK button?)

Or is it better to manually assign SettingsDialog's controls' values from business data while SettingsDialog is showing, and then assign them back only if user presses OK button?

What are arguments of correct choice (smaller or clearer code, performance, extensibility)?

Is there some acknowledged design pattern for similar cases?

**EDIT:** I marked Bubblewrap's answer as accepted, because it fits my own concrete case the most. Though, Guard's and John's answers also seem  acceptable.

To summarize: using data binding has some advantages.
It allows SettingsDialog to know nothing about business object internal connections and dependencies (if there are any), allows to switch later from modal to non-modal mode easily, reduces dependencies between GUI and business data.

To implement changing of object upon OK button click, object cloning/assigning may be used, or object may implement IEditableObject interface.

In some trivial cases, though, using data binding may have some unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have encountered similar requirements before, and prefer two variants, both using databinding.

In the first variant we clone the object and bind to the clone. When the user presses OK, the cloned object replaces to real object. This is mostly useful when editing one object at a time, and the object is not referenced directly by other objects. If it is referenced, then instead you could copy the values from your clone to your original, so that references remain intact. This saves work because no extra work is required in the editors, at most you must define 2 methods on your object, a Clone and possible an Apply method to copy the values from the clone.

The second variant we bind to the original object, but we store the original values in our editing dialog, either in local fields or in a temporary data-object. When the user presses OK, nothing special has to happen, but when the user presses cancel we revert the values. This is mostly useful when you edit only a few simple properties in the dialog.

I prefer databinding solutions because it doesnt pollute the editing dialogs with apply/cancel logic, which if implemented in the editors is very dependent on your XAML: controls can be renamed, a combobox can be replaced by a textbox etc, all of which would affect code which manually assings data from controls.

The Clone/Apply methods only need to be on your business objects, which in theory are more stable than your UI editors. Even if the XAML changes, in most cases your bindings can remain the same. For example a change from combobox to textbox only means you bind to Text instead of SelectedValue, but the actual binding is the same.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to have your business object implement [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx).

- Before showing the window, call [BeginEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.beginedit.aspx) on your object
- If the user clicks OK, call [EndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.endedit.aspx)
- If the user clicks Cancel, call [CancelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.canceledit.aspx)

IEditableObject is typically used in data grid scenarios, but it works well for the case you described too.  Plus, if your UI ever changes to allow inline editing in a DataGrid, you won't have to change your business object.

Comment: Thank you!

I've taken the IEditableObject route and I don't regret it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data-binding for one-way updating to the GUI, but if you want to postpone updating the business model only after OK is pressed, it's better to do this in code. Data-binding at all in this case may be unnecessary.

Take, for example, `FolderBrowserDialog`. You can set an initial value to `SelectedPath` before you call `ShowDialog()`, but you wait for the dialog to return with `DialogResult.OK` before you process the data. A similar approach should work for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

On Form Load handler Go over Bindings collection and set each DataSourceUpdateMode to Never.
On OK handler set to opposite (DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation) and call form ValidateChildren

if binding done through GUI there would be new form member of class BindingSource 
It simplifies a bit - bindings acessible by CurrencyManager.Bindings, and BindingSource.EndEdit can be used instead of ValidateChildren.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered same problem - I have popup dialog forms to edit object properties. After some tweaking I ended up with the code below, which seems to work well. Hope it helps someone.

I use this to show the popup form

```
    public static bool EditTask(MyTask task)
    {
        //make a backup object in case user clicks Cancel
        MyTask backupTask = new MyTask();
        CloneObject(task, backupTask);

        //dialog form uses data binding to the backupTask object
        MyTaskWindow f = new MyTaskWindow(backupTask);

        f.ShowDialog();
        if (f.DialogResult.HasValue && f.DialogResult.Value)
        {
            //user clicked "Ok" - clone everything back
            CloneObject(backupTask, task);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {                
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Reflection is used to clone object
    //copied from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/deep-copy-of-object-in-C-Sharp/
    private static void CloneObject(object objSource, object objTarget)
    {
        //step : 1 Get the type of source object and create a new instance of that type
        Type typeSource = objSource.GetType();
        //object objTarget = Activator.CreateInstance(typeSource);

        //Step2 : Get all the properties of source object type
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = typeSource.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        //Step : 3 Assign all source property to taget object 's properties
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in propertyInfo)
        {
            //Check whether property can be written to
            if (property.CanWrite)
            {
                //Step : 4 check whether property type is value type, enum or string type
                if (property.PropertyType.IsValueType || property.PropertyType.IsEnum || property.PropertyType.Equals(typeof(System.String)))
                {
                    property.SetValue(objTarget, property.GetValue(objSource, null), null);
                }
                //else property type is object/complex types, so need to recursively call this method until the end of the tree is reached
                else
                {
                    object objPropertyValue = property.GetValue(objSource, null);
                    if (objPropertyValue == null)
                    {
                        property.SetValue(objTarget, null, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Type newTypeSource = objPropertyValue.GetType();
                        object newObjTarget = Activator.CreateInstance(newTypeSource);
                        CloneObject(objPropertyValue, newObjTarget);
                        property.SetValue(objTarget, newObjTarget, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```